# Compare an aggregate to another aggregate with window functions

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

The following query (tested with Postgresql 11.1) evaluates, for each customer/product combination, the following elements:

- (A) the sum of sales value that the customer spent on this product
- (B) the sum of sales value that the customer spent in the parent category of this product

And divides A / B to get to a metric called `loyalty`.

```
select
  pp.customer, pp.product, pp.category,
  pp.sales_product / pc.sales_category as loyalty
from (
    select
      t.household_key as customer,
      t.product_id as product,
      p.commodity as category,
      sum(t.sales_value) as sales_product
    from transaction_data t
    left join product p on p.product_id = t.product_id
    group by t.household_key, t.product_id, p.commodity
) pp
left join (
    select
      t.household_key as customer,
      p.commodity as category,
      sum(t.sales_value) as sales_category
    from transaction_data t
    left join product p on p.product_id = t.product_id
    group by t.household_key, p.commodity
) pc on pp.customer = pc.customer and pp.category = pc.category
;
```

Results are of this form:

```
customer      product    category     loyalty
---------------------------------------------
       1       tomato        food        0.01
       1         beef        food        0.02
       1   toothpaste     hygiene        0.04
       1   toothbrush     hygiene        0.03
```

My question is, instead of having to rely on two sub-queries which are then left-joined, would it be feasible with a single query using window functions instead?

I've tried to do something like the following, but obviously this doesn't work because, in this case, `column "t.sales_value" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`. I don't see what can be done to fix this.

```
-- does not work
select
  t.household_key as customer,
  t.product_id as product,
  p.commodity as category,
  sum(t.sales_value) as sales_product,
  sum(t.sales_value) over (partition by t.household_key, p.commodity) as sales_category
from transaction_data t
left join product p on p.product_id = t.product_id
group by t.household_key, t.product_id, p.commodity;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do this without using either a join or a subquery, but here is one way to do this with a subquery, using analytic functions:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        t.household_key AS customer,
        t.product_id AS product,
        p.commodity as category,
        SUM(t.sales_value) OVER (PARTITION BY t.household_key, t.product_id, p.commodity)
            AS sales_product,
        SUM(t.sales_value) OVER (PARTITION BY t.household_key, p.commodity)
            AS sales_category
    FROM transaction_data t
    LEFT JOIN product p
        ON p.product_id = t.product_id
)

SELECT
    t.customer,
    t.product,
    t.category
    MAX(t.sales_product) / MAX(t.sales_category) AS loyalty
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    t.customer,
    t.product,
    t.category;
```

The trick here is to make a single pass over your joined tables, and use analytic sum to compute the aggregates you want, with two different partitions, one with 2 columns and the other with three columns.  Then, we can aggregate by 3 columns and just arbitrarily take the max value of the aggregates for each group.

Comment: It works but for some reason it seems slower than the original one. I'm digging in because there are some inconsistencies due to null values in the data.